# Github Authentication Failed - ... GitHub does not provide shell access

Tags: git, github, ssh-keys

```
$ git remote add origin git@github.com:lut/EvolutionApp.git
fatal: remote origin already exists.

$ git push -u origin master
fatal: 'EvolutionApp' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

My keys were added succesfully

```
 $ ssh -T git@github.com
 Hi lut! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```

The Github article https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys/ says that "Shell access" should not be an issue? What could the problem be?

Comment: What do you see from `git remote show origin`?

Comment: $ git remote show origin
fatal: 'EvolutionApp' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

Comment: @SLaks it says is does not appear to be a Git repository, but previously it said that it already exists. I dont get it.

Answer (score 145, accepted):

Try and redefine the ssh url for remote origin:

```
git remote set-url origin git@github.com:lut/EvolutionApp.git
```

And try again.

Only [`git remote set-url`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote#Documentation/git-remote.txt-emset-urlem) can change an existing remote URL (as opposed to [`git remote add`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote#Documentation/git-remote.txt-emaddem), to *add* a *new* remote name and URL)
Here, the issue was the URL of the existing remote '`origin`', `EvolutionApp`: it needed to be *replaced* by a valid one.
Using `git config url."ssh://git@github.com/".insteadOf https://github.com/` would not have helped, considering there was no HTTPS URL in the first place.

Comment: Thanks VonC.  This was driving me crazy till I found your post. Godspeed.

Comment: Why does github have within their docs that they do not allow shell access?  This is confusing.  https://help.github.com/articles/testing-your-ssh-connection/

Comment: @brohjoe Because `ssh -T git@github.com` only gives you a "Welcome" message, *not* an interactive shell.

Comment: @MoshtabaDarzi I am sorry it does not work. Could you ask a separate question with more details for me or others to have a look?

Comment: `git pull origin master --allow-unrelated-histories` may help.

Answer (score 19):

You can add this in the `~/.gitconfig` file.

```
[url "ssh://git@github.com/"]
        insteadOf = https://github.com/
```

Now ssh will be used instead of https.

Answer (score 3):

I also encountered this problem when moving from one repository to another. I had already used this Git account before in other projects and there was already a ssh key there that was successfully used by other servers. But it was impossible to upload the key from my new server. I had to make a new key and upload a second one to the repository.
Old key I tried upload git has ignored it whithout any error messages.

```bash
#rename old repository
git remote rename origin origin_old

#adding new address of repository
git remote add origin git@github.com:you_mail/your_project.git

#creating new ssh key
ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -C "you_mail@mail.com"

eval `ssh-agent`
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_ed25519
```

Now, upload **id_ed25519.pub** to git. Check presence of this file in your account!

```bash
git remote set-url origin git@github.com:you_mail/your_project.git
git push -u origin master
git remote set-head origin master
```

Answer (score 2):

You might have to add the remote again. That error message happens when Git doesn't know where to push to.

Use `git remote -v` check if the remote exists, if not, add it.

Even then if it doesn't work try removing the `GIT_SSH` environment variable, this maybe causing the problem.

Comment: $ git remote -v
origin EvolutionApp (fetch)
origin EvolutionApp (push)

Comment: Could this message that pops up when Terminal launches be causing the issue? -bash: /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh: No such file or directory

Answer (score 1):

This can happen if you have an incomplete remote entry in your global config.

Run `git config -e --system`, comment out any `[remote` entries, re-add the remote, and try again.

Comment: $ git config -e --system
subl -w: subl: command not found
error: There was a problem with the editor 'subl -w'.

Comment: Your git editor is misconfigured.  Either install Sublime or configure it to use a different editor.

Comment: I ran git config --global core.editor "subl -n -w" but still get an error. I can succesfully open Sublime from Terminal with open /Applications/Sublime\ Text\ 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl I think I has something to do with my profile. Everytime I open a new terminal window I get -bash: /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh: No such file or directory

Answer (score 1):

check if you are using `https` as remote url instead of `ssh`. 
I set my remote url to `http` and encountered this issue. After resetting the url to `ssh` protocol the problem is gone.

Answer (score 0):

if there is trust issue for android studio or vs code project in git
You can give safe permissions like below , with your project path in Ubuntu

git config --global --add safe.directory '_your_project_path'

`git config --global --add safe.directory '/data/project/project/MyApp/android_app'`

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this error while trying to clone a repo on Cent OS 8.

I had to use `https` instead of `ssh` to clone and it successfully worked