# Github push over ssh fails while test works

Tags: git, github, windows-10, ssh-keygen, mobaxterm

I have generated 4096 RSA certificate, registered it locally with ssh-add and in github. I followed official documentation. The ssh works and I am authenticated, but I cannot push my local repository to github. The origin URL was copied from github repository setting.

Test ssh connection is working:

```
>ssh -T git@github.com
warning: agent returned different signature type ssh-rsa (expected rsa-sha2-512)
Hi leosliterak! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```

But git push does not:

```
>git push -u origin master
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.
```

And git repository URL:

```
git remote get-url origin
git@github.com:leosliterak/console.git
```

I am really confused that the push is denied while ssh with the same certificate is OK.

```
>ssh-add -L
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABJQAAAgEAqllZxcxhD0gT650= c:\Users\leos\.ssh\id_rsa
```

Comment: This might be a possible solution. Give it a shot: [github-authentication-failed-github-does-not-provide-shell-access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26953071/github-authentication-failed-github-does-not-provide-shell-access)

Comment: No, it does not help. I tried to set the origin url again and there is no change.

Comment: Did you add the ssh key to you git hub account? [Add SSH Key to GitHUB](https://help.github.com/en/articles/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account). This issue can technically mean two things: a) The ssh key was not added to GitHub account b)The ssh key at the host is not added to the agent correctly.

Comment: Yes I did: "Hi leosliterak! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access."

Comment: I agree with @rahulqelfo. (assuming normal settings) `cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | clip` paste into github's SSH key settings. And you should be good to go. if you don't have an id_rsa.pub file make one with `ssh-keygen`.

Comment: Ok, it works now. I deleted the key and generated it again from the command line. Originally I used ssh-keygen bundled in MobaXTerm.