# How to authenticate against two separate Github repos on the same server using SSH keys?

Tags: git, github, ssh

We've got a test server running Ubuntu 20.04. The project we're testing has a Vue based Web app & a PHP based CMS.

Each component has its own repo in Github:

```
OurCompany/project-app
OurCompany/project-cms
```

On the test server the Git repos are in these directories:

```
/home/root/app-build
/var/www/cms
```

Both have deploy scripts that run `git pull` to update the code with the latest changes from the repo. Authentication is via SSH deploy keys.

I've been following the [Github instructions here](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/developers/overview/managing-deploy-keys#using-multiple-repositories-on-one-server) which say I need to change the configuration SSH config file to use different SSH keys:

```
Host github.com-project-app
        Hostname github.com
        IdentityFile=/home/root/.ssh/app_deploy_key

Host github.com-project-cms
        Hostname github.com
        IdentityFile=/home/root/.ssh/cms_deploy_key
```

I've also updated the repos in `/home/root/app-build/.git/config` & `/var/www/cms/.git/config` to

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = git@github.com-project-app:OurCompany/project-app.git
```

&

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = git@github.com-project-cms:OurCompany/project-cms.git
```

In theory, we should now be to access both repos with their matching deploy keys?

But instead, only `project-cms` authenticates & testing SSH returns the following:

```
#ssh -T git@github.com-project-cms
Hi OurCompany/project-cms! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.

#ssh -T git@github.com-project-app
Hi OurCompany/project-cms! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```

So it's only authenticating to `project-cms` even with the `project-app` hostname.

Any ideas about what's going on & how I can fix it?

Comment: Check this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26953071/github-authentication-failed-github-does-not-provide-shell-access

Comment: Are the public keys in the two files, `/home/root/.ssh/{app_deploy_key,cms_deploy_key}`, actually different? If not, that immediately explains the results of the two `ssh` attempts. But I also wonder why, if you're a single entity, you want to authenticate to GitHub first as Fred Flintstone, then moments later as Barney Rubble. Why not make both repositories accessible to Fred, and access both as Fred?

Comment: @torek - the Github documentation says  "You can't reuse a deploy key for multiple repositories." - I'll ignore that, use the same key & see what happens.

Comment: I don't know if they *check* for that. If they don't check, again, you'd see the same problem. It's not a good idea to use the same deploy key because the purpose of a *deploy* key is to identify a deployment (on any machine, rather than a particular machine). You should always think about authentication as specifying *who you are*, separate from permissions which specify *what that person is allowed to do*. Machine keys are specific to machines so that we can tell, from logs, which machine it was; deploy keys are specific to applications, so that we can tell which app it was.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure:

- `/home/root/.ssh/app_deploy_key` is different from `/home/root/.ssh/cms_deploy_key`,
- `/home/root/.ssh/app_deploy_key.pub` public [deploy key](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/developers/overview/managing-deploy-keys#deploy-keys) is registered to the correct GitHub `project-app` "Deploy Keys" settings.